# Were there written (draft) Soviet proposals that would have effectively restricted the US navy from (parts of) Europe?

Tags: united-states, soviet-union, cold-war, diplomacy

I'm pretty sure that if one trawls the Soviet propaganda, one can find something asking Americans to bugger off from Europe altogether (ok, on a more serious note--Gorbatchev [did](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1986-04-22-mn-1429-story.html) propose the simultaneous dissolution of NATO and the Warsaw Pact), but I'm wonder on the level of more concrete semi-serious--as in written--military proposals, did they ever ask the US navy to stay at a certain distance from the USSR territories (as Russia did in a 2021 draft treaty, which the US rejected)? And what [if anything] were the Soviets willing to offer in return?

Comment: Modern Russia and the USSR are very different entities both politically and geopolitically. So I'm not sure that Russia doing something alone is sufficient reason to expect the USSR might have done the same thing.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Eh, maybe not so different in this (NATO) regard, for instance? Both Stalin and Putin asked to join NATO, for instance.